# Bigcommerce Class 'Bigcommerce\Api\Error' not found

Tags: bigcommerce

I keep getting this error when I try to execute a simple script on the server while it runs fine on my local machine.

**Error**

> Fatal error: Class 'Bigcommerce\Api\Error' not found in
>   /customers/0/4/1/myDomainName/httpd.www/demo/hello/bigcommerce.php on
>   line 370

link to [**API**](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php)

**Sample Code**

```
require_once 'bigcommerce.php';
use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'https://www.mystore.com/',
    'username' => 'myUsername',
    'api_key' => 'myPass'
));

Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

?>
```

Php Version

- Server: `5.3.23`
- Local: `5.3.13`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by moving the declaration of `class Error` to just above the `line 370` where class `ClientError` was declared.